# Using AI service to recognize a free text search field question?

Tags: nlp

Is there an API service, paid or not paid (IBM Watson, Google Natural Language), that can accept a free text "ask a question" field and convert it into a set of keywords to be used for a regular keyword search?

For example if my website has a search field "Ask a question about our products", and a user types in "Do you have red dresses?", is there an API we can integrate into our code that can just convert this to "red dress" which we then simply feed into our regular keyword search for "red dress"?

Ideally it can handle variations of questions such as:

"How do you return a product?" -- return product
"Do you accept Mastercard?" -- mastercard
"Where can I find blue shoes?" -- blue shoes

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please review the submission guidelines in stackoverflow.com/help.  With that said, you may conferge on your solution faster by filtering out common expressions to arrive at your key words, ie, "How do you return a product?" filters out "How do you" and "a".  You could have a training mechanism to do this and arrive at your desired results very quickly.

Comment: Did the extract noun chunk approach work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract noun chunks and then use those as keywords.
For example using Spacy, you can extract noun chunks as follows:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

def getNounChunks(doc):
    inc = ['NN', 'NNP', 'NNPS', 'NNS', 'JJ', 'HYPH']
    incn = ['NN', 'NNP', 'NNPS' ,'NNS']
    excl = ['other', 'some', 'many', 'certain', 'various']
    lspans = []
    chunk =[]
    for t in doc:
        if t.text.lower() in excl:
            continue
        if chunk:
            if chunk[-1].tag_ == 'HYPH':
                chunk.append(t)
                continue

        if t.tag_ in inc:
            if t.tag_ != 'JJ':
                chunk.append(t)
            else:
                if not any([t.tag_ in incn for t in chunk]):
                    chunk.append(t)

        else:
            if chunk:
                if any([t.tag_ in incn for t in chunk]):
                    lspans.append(doc[chunk[0].i:chunk[-1].i + 1])
                chunk = list()
    return(lspans)


questions = [
"How do you return a product?" ,
"Do you accept Mastercard?" ,
"Where can I find blue shoes?",
"Do you have red dresses?",]

for q in questions:
    doc = nlp(q)
    print(getNounChunks(doc))

#output:
#[product]
#[Mastercard]
#[blue shoes]
#[red dresses]
```